# Excel custom text format to align by first character when justified center or right

Tags: microsoft-excel

By default, a center-justified row with the `Text` format looks like:

[image]

I want the text to be center-justified in the cell **and** aligned by the first character, like:

[image]

Or

[image]

And if it is right-justified:

[image]

The solutions are fairly simple with formulas or VBA, but can these 3 formats be accomplished with custom formats? And with a variable number of characters? Probably not a variable number of characters because correct me if I am wrong, custom formats require you to define specific lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effect by using **Align Left** on the cells and then using **Increase Indent** to move the left edge to the right.

Comment: Thank you, but I want the alignment to be used properly.

Comment: With a percentage that I know will only be 1-2 digits, I can use `?0%`. But I can't seem to do `?@` for text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom format for cells:

```
;;;         @
```

[image]